# using printf with C++ iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm not clearly understanding what's happening when I use std::printf with an iterator in this context:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
   std::string str{"hello, world"};
   std::printf("%s\n", str.begin()); // prints "hello, world"
   std::vector<char> vec(str.begin(), str.end());
   std::printf("%s\n", vec.begin()); // still same output
   std::list<char> lst(str.begin(), str.end());
   std::printf("%s\n", lst.begin()); // weird ascii outputs ???
}
```

I also used <stdarg.h> utilities to simulate printf's behavior and it looks like it still works even with `va_arg(ap, char*)` and behaves the same way as the code above, and I got couple of questions.
Does it work on arrays that are contiguous (with a RAI iterator) ? or it's UB ? Why even `va_arg` will allow such thing, is there some implicit conversions ?

Comment: UB... you're accessing raw data and interpreting it in some other format

Comment: but why does it always work with `std::string` and `std::vector` iterators ?

Comment: What's happening is that you're using a C++ class with a C library function that has no clue, whatsoever, about anything that's related to C++. Any sensible results you may or may not see are purely random luck. `printf` is not guaranteed to work with any iterator, or a C++ class, and even if does work today, it may mysteriously stop working the next time you update your C++ compiler, or maybe it'll stop working next Monday, if it feels like it.

Comment: @simamt Undefined Behaviour is undefined, this includes "seemingly works as expected". But your assumption is probably correct, contiguous containers are most likely to seemingly work in this context.

Comment: The `vector<char>` you get is not null terminated so even if `vec.begin()` was guaranteed to return a plain `char*` you'd read out of bounds - UB

Comment: While technically UB, adding `&*` by doing this `&*str.begin()` is defined.

Comment: Why not use [`std::string::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data), which for default strings is defined to be null terminated and equivalent to `std::string::c_str`.

Comment: @doug Yes, but `&*vec.begin()`, `vec.data()` or `&vec[0]` is not..

Comment: @simant -- An iterator is whatever the compiler says it is.  It is not guaranteed to merely be a pointer.  If you want a real-world example of how bad erroneously assuming iterators are pointers, the Visual C++ compiler used to implement vector iterators as pointers.  A whole lot of code written for Visual C++ also assumed this, and the programs worked.  Then along comes a newer version of the VC++ compiler, and all of that code was now broken since the iterator was now a `struct`.  If the programmer treated iterators as iterators and not pointers, then the code wouldn't have been broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: It's all invalid C++**, since `std::printf` doesn't have a type safe API. **Passing references to non-POD objects as `std::printf` arguments is always invalid**: `printf` has a C API.

What's happening in all cases is undefined behavior: you should not be writing code like that. The language spec itself tells you nothing about what to expect. Such code is a bug and would fail any sensible code review.

For the case of `std::string` and `std::vector` iterators, they happen to have the same size, value, layout, and parameter passing convention *on your platform* as a `const char *` that `printf` expects, *and* they happen to contain addresses of the beginning of the string/vector, respectively. Both `std::string` and `std::vector<char>` lay out the data array identically, i.e. the elements are contiguous, and coincidentially the memory block in `std::vector` has a zero at the end of the string, so this happens to work. Maybe it only works because you build in debug mode :)

For the case of `std::list` iterator, it probably happens to contain a pointer to  either the header of the list's data block, or a pointer to the beginning of `std::string` wrapped in the list item, and thus you get nonsense output that nevertheless doesn't cause an invalid memory access, since the equivalent pointer points to some allocated memory area and is otherwise valid. This is a consequence of implementation details on your platform, of course. There are platforms and build options where that code will just crash. And no, you can't even depend that it will crash dependably. That's why UB is pretty bad.

On your platform, `std::printf("%s\n", *lst.begin());` would probably be just as bad of a bug yet happen to "work", since `*lst.begin()` produces a reference to `std::string`, and such a reference usually is laid out and passed around like a pointer would be. This is still UB of course, so don't do any of it!